# Event / Emit naming Convention

Tags: events, rinkeby

When I deploy the exact same contract on Rinkeby, other than the name of the event, Rinkeby behaves differently.  When the Event's name is OwnerSet I can see that on https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/.  However, when the name is OwnerSit I don't see the event's name.  See below pictures and code.

Why the difference in behavior?

Thank you

[image: OwnerSet]

[image: OwnerSit]

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity 0.7.4;

contract Owner {

    address public owner;
    
    // Time this contract was created
    uint256 public createTime;
    
    // event for EVM logging
    event OwnerSet(address indexed oldOwner, address indexed newOwner);
    
    // modifier to check if caller is owner
    modifier isOwner() {
        
        require(msg.sender == owner, "Caller is not owner.");
        _;
    }
    
    constructor() {
        
        owner = msg.sender;
        createTime = block.timestamp;
        emit OwnerSet(address(0), owner);
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you re-verified the contract after changing the event's name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably not about Rinkeby, but about Etherscan, which is also what I think goodvibration is implying in the comment on your question. If you take the keccak256 hash of `OwnerSit(address,address)` (called the event signature), you should get the `0x3411...` you see in `[topic0]` in the screenshot. That should tell you that the contract (or at least the event) is properly deployed to Rinkeby.

So why isn't the event name showing up on Etherscan? In order for Etherscan to know the information displayed in the first screen shot, it needs to be [submitted to Etherscan](https://etherscan.io/verifyContract). This is the process called contract verification (like goodvibration mentioned). Here's a link that can walk you through it, if you need some help with the process: https://dave-appleton.medium.com/verifying-your-contract-on-etherscan-75a2afbf5b42

Hope that helps!

Comment: That worked.  I now see OwnerSit on EtherScan.  Thank you.  Follow up question:  Why when I deployed the original contract with OwnerSet, the Event name showed up on EtherScan without me having to Verify the contract.  Thank you.

Comment: I can only guess, but it could be that they check bytecode against bytecodes that have already been verified, so if you were using a template or something like that, it could be someone else submitted it.

Comment: Yes I was using a template from Remix.  Thank you The Renaissance.